# How to merge 2 NSDictionaries in NSMutableArray having same value in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with NSDictionaries like below format

```
(
            {
        "login_id" = 95;
        consDays = "Mon,Tue";
        consEndTime = 12600000;
        consStartTime = 9000000;
        duration = 10;
        id = 58;
        isActive = 1;
    },
            {
        "login_id" = 95;
        consDays = "Wed,Thur";
        consEndTime = 41400000;
        consStartTime = 23400000;
        duration = 10;
        id = 59;
        isActive = 1;
    },
            {
        "login_id" = 98;
        consDays = "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat,Sun";
        consEndTime = 45000000;
        consStartTime = 9000000;
        duration = 30;
        id = 60;
        isActive = 1;
    },
```

I can see here first 2 object's with "login_id" 95 are same and i need to merge the contents and make something like this one

```
      {
        "login_id" = 95;
        consDays = "Mon,Tue-Wed,Thur";
        consEndTime = 12600000-41400000;
        consStartTime = 9000000-23400000;
        duration = 10;
        id = 58;
        isActive = 1;
    },
```

i have tried with for loop and its not getting clear

```
for(int i=0;i<[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] count];i++){

    NSString *bloginId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"branchLogin_id"] objectAtIndex:i]];

    for(int j=0;j<[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] count];j++){

        NSString *firstId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"branchLogin_id"] objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSString *secondId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"branchLogin_id"] objectAtIndex:j]];
        NSLog(@"%@-%@",firstId,secondId);

        if([firstId isEqualToString:secondId]){
            NSLog(@"%@",[consultationDetailsArray valueForKey:@"branchLogin_id"]);
            if([[consultationDetailsArray valueForKey:@"branchLogin_id"]  containsObject:secondId]){

                NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[[consultationDetailsArray valueForKey:@"consDays"] objectAtIndex:j],[[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"consDays"] objectAtIndex:j]];
                NSLog(@"consDays %@",str);

            }else{

                [consultationDetailsArray addObject:[[arr valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:j]];
            }
        }
    }



}
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you please add the results printed in console by the NSLogs also?
And can you give the value of your arr object too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically I am doing just this same thing right now. Looks like the easiest way is to use a NSMutableDictionary.

```
    // Assume two starting dictionaries.
    dictionaryOne;
    dictionaryTwo;
    //
    // Create a mutable copy of the first
    NSMutableDictionary *merged = dictionaryOne.mutableCopy;
    [merged addEntriesFromDictionary: dictionaryTwo];
    //
    // merged now contains all keys of both dictionaries
    // keys that are in both dictionaries will have values
    // from dictionaryTwo.
```

Hope this helps.